# How does Activity.finish() work in Android?

Tags: java, android

Could someone provide a description of what happens when an `Activity` calls its `finish()` method?

Does it exit immediately, or does it complete the function from which it was called?

Comment: Related thread - [what exactly Activity.finish() method is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847526/465053)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

> Does it exits immediately or completes
>   the function from which it was called
>   ?

The method that called `finish()` will run to completion. The `finish()` operation will not even begin until you return control to Android.

Comment: Then how to finish an activity which is called by StartAvtivityforResults() without completion?

Comment: @CommonsWare How we can ensure that onStop is called always ? In my app OnStop and onDestroy are not called in some cases and in those cases the child activity takes too much time in finishing and that looks like App has hanged... Whereas when onStop is called everything works normal. I am on Galaxy y with Android 2.3.6... see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928591/a-strange-behavior-of-android-activities-fragments-and-intent plz help!!!

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested sir very true.+1 for you But I wanna ask one question I have written finish() as an first statement in my function then it is executing the whole function and then finish() is called How this managed.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, you could have your function return right after finish() is called.

Comment: Does finish() also call onPause() and onStop() before calling onDestroy() ?

Comment: @user3282164: If the activity is not paused and stopped already, yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am performing same way but Activity can not finish.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233422/finish-activity-not-close-in-android-xamarin?noredirect=1#comment67730214_40233422

Answer (score 21):

Every life cycle event like `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onPause`.... `onDestroy` of an Activity is always called on a single thread - The "Main thread".

In short this thread is backed by a Queue into which all the activity events are getting posted.
This thread can execute all these events in the order of insertion.

If you are calling `finish()` in one of the life cycle callbacks like `onCreate()`...a "finish" message will get added to this queue but the thread is not free to pick & execute "finish" action
until currently executing method returns i.e Thread is freed from current task.

Answer (score 13):

`ondestroy()` is the final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.

This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called `finish()`  on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()`  method.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two activities A and B. And your flow is going from A > B; and B=A calls `finish()`.

Then,

The method where you called `finish()` from will execute as Mark mentioned. And flow of callbacks will be as followed -

1. `onPause()` of `activity A`
2. `onRestart()` > `onStart()` > `onResume()` of Activity B
3. Then, comes the real difference. If you did not call `finish()` from `activity A`; only `onStop()` of `Activity A` will be called here. While, in this case, where we called `finish()` from `Activity A`; So `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` both will be called for `activity A`.