# Calling finish() on an Android activity doesn't actually finish

Tags: android

I'm calling `finish()` but my activity keeps on going.

I have an activity which is invoked by a menu from the main activity screen.  In my activity's `onCreate()` method I have the following code fragment:

```
    // Make sure there are some events in the list.
    if (theEventArrayList.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Event List is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    SummarizeCurrentEvent();
    graphEvents();
```

If the list is empty it puts up the Toast, and I can set breakpoint on the call to `finish()`. If I step from that in the debugger it goes to straight to `SummarizeCurrentEvent()`.   I thought `finish()` would exit the activity. Is this not the case? Where can I find out more information about this method?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should put a `return` statement after that `finish`, because the method that called `finish` will be executed completely otherwise.

also, see this question: [about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put `SummarizeCurrentEvent(); graphEvents();...` in an `else {}` block?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering You could potentially have multiple ``if (...) { finish(); return; }``.  I think it's a good habit to explicitly ``finish()`` **and** ``return``  when there's code following.

Answer (score 7):

finish() just tells the activity to do what it needs to do to finish, eg. shutdown, call on onPause, report result to parent, etc. It doesn't do an exit() call or anything.

You should return after the finish() call.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the other answers, you still **may** have `(Re)onStart`,  `onResume` and `onPause` invoked.

I say this because in the following link, there is a table that says that for one activity to be killed, first it is invoked onPause (and probably but not guaranteed) on Stop and onDestroy.

Reference [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

put in manifest :

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to avoid holding it in  history stack of the system

Answer (score 0):

Finish finishes the activity, but it's up to the main loop to do any UI interaction. You have to wait until the UI loop runs, which is after you return from `onCreate`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the case where the `try...catch` statement should be used.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        //...some initialization...

        // Make sure there are some events in the list.
        if (theEventArrayList.isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Event List is empty");
        }
        SummarizeCurrentEvent();
        graphEvents();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```