# How to completely finish my activity, and after activity.finish no further code will execute?

Tags: android

I want to completely finish my activity, and after activity.finish no further code will execute?

Example:

```
Intent scoringOpponentTeam = new Intent(this,TestActivitySecond.class);
startActivity(scoringOpponentTeam);
this.finish();
Log.i("after Finish Called", "after Finish Called--------"+"after Finish Called");
```

In above example, I want that no `Log.i()` line will execute.

Comment: Put a break statement after your finish() call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling finish() on an Android activity doesn't actually finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924071/calling-finish-on-an-android-activity-doesnt-actually-finish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `finish()`, Android will let your code in the specific block after the `finish()` call execute, and that is why the log message appears. A simple `return` statement after the `finish()` call is the solution.

However, there is no need for you to explicity "kill" your `Activity` since Android handles this perfectly on its own.

Comment: but sir my situation is that these lines are exist method within a method, and in parent method are calling 25 places, where different code exist(or some other exist which i want not execute but in your suggestion when method call complete, that line execute), I Simply want I complete exit from this activity, neither a single line execute after that.

Comment: Elaborate your code. From what you've wrote in the comment above your code isn't properly designed.

Answer (score 0):

this.finish();
**return;**

Comment: but sir my situation is that these lines are exist method within a method, and in parent method are calling 25 places, where different code exist(or some other exist which i want not execute but in your suggestion when method call complete, that line execute), I Simply want I complete exit from this activity, neither a single line execute after that

Answer (score 0):

You need a **return** statement after your this.finish();

Comment: but return statement only return from this method and code after that method call will execute. i will not execute any single line after that.