# Finish Theme.Transluscent.NoTitleBar?

Tags: android, themes, activity-finish

I have an android activity with Theme=Theme.Transluscent.NoTitleBar.

I want to use finish this kind of activity using finish() but it doesnt work. As it is an invisible activity it goes to onPause State rather than onDestroy state.

How can I overcome this problem as it uses unnecessary memory.

Thank YOU !!

Comment: Even on calling finish() it does not close it?

Comment: nopes
after finish() i put a Toast it shows Toast message !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many threads which explain this. When you are calling `finish()`, Android will let your code in the specific block after the `finish()` call execute, and that is why the Toast message appears. A simple return statement after the `finish()` call is the solution. Taken from  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750685/1306419)  on question:

[Android Help! I want to completely finish my activity, and after activity.finish no further code will execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750542/android-help-i-want-to-completely-finish-my-activity-and-after-activity-finish)

Other relevant ones are:

[Calling finish() on an Android activity doesn't actually finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924071/calling-finish-on-an-android-activity-doesnt-actually-finish)

[about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `System.exit(0);` but as stated it is not a good approach. but however you can use this approach to clear the previous activity `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
.