# Activity not destroying completely

Tags: android

I have an application with the following activities:

```
A->B->C
```

On `C` I am using the following code to play an mp3 file in loop when my web service returns true (which we check for periodically):

```
void PlayBeepLoop()
{

    try {
        if(player.isPlaying())
            return;

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("beep.mp3");
        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        player.prepare();
        player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I go from `C->B` on pressing back, I believe the loop keeps on running and it beeps when it returns true.

Following code on `C` also does not work:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Please help
PS: I need the beep to stop only when the back button is pressed. Pressing home button while app is still showing `C` should allow the beeps to happen, when the app is in background.

Comment: Try stopping the loop in some way before you call `finish();`.

Comment: if the entire activity is gone, why media player still stays alive ?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924071/calling-finish-on-an-android-activity-doesnt-actually-finish

Answer (score 0):

Remove super.onBackPressed() and add @Override above your onBackPressed() method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
finish();
```

use

```
player.stop();
finish();
```