# onCreate flow continues after finish()

Tags: android, oncreate

I would like to finish an activity from inside the `onCreate` method. When I call `finish()`, `onDestroy()` is not immediately called, the code keeps flowing past `finish()`. `onDestroy()` isn't called until after the `onCreate()` closing brace.

Per the `onCreate()` description at developer.android.com/reference.

> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case
>   onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest of the
>   activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.

Reason I ask is: I would like to check data from the Bundle passed to `onCreate()`. Of course I have control of what is passed to `onCreate`, but I still think it should be checked at the point of delivery.

My code contains class `A`, which starts Activity `B`. I believe the last two "outside of if clause" tags, shouldn't be called because the `finish` method in the `if` statement should have destroyed the activity.  It has nothing to do with the if clause because the tag line after the second `finish()` call is still also read.

My Code:

Class A

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // goToBButton: when pressed sends message to class B.    
    Button goToBButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.go_to__b_btn);
    goToBButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {      
            Log.i(TAG,"A Class: goToBButton, onClick");
            Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,REQ_TO_B);
        }       
    });                
} // end onCreate
```

My Code ClassB

```
    public class B extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "tag";

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.layoutb);

  // set as true, should always print Tag: one line before first finish"
  if (true)  {

    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: one line before 1st finish");
    finish();
  }

  // shouldn't get here after first finish
  Log.i(TAG,"B Class: outside of if clause, before second finish");
  finish();
  // shouldn't get here after second finish
  Log.i(TAG,"B Class: outside of if clause, after finish");                  
   } // end onCreate


@Override
public void onStart () {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onStart");
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onRestart");
}

@Override
public void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause () {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG,"B Class: onDestroy");
}

 } // end B Class
```

Here are the results of my tags:

> 11-26 15:53:40.456: INFO/tag(699): A Class: goToBButton, onClick
>
> 11-26 15:53:40.636: INFO/tag(699): A Class: onPause
>
> 11-26 15:53:40.865: INFO/tag(699): B Class: one line before 1st finish
>
> 11-26 15:53:40.896: INFO/tag(699): B Class: outside of if clause,
>   before second finish
>
> 11-26 15:53:40.917: INFO/tag(699): B Class: outside of if clause,
>   after finish
>
> 11-26 15:53:41.035: INFO/tag(699): A Class: onResume
>
> 11-26 15:53:41.165: INFO/tag(699): B Class: onDestroy

Comment: "immediately" was a very poor word choice in the docs...

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I'm guessing that it is because finish() doesn't cause the onCreate method to return. You could try simply adding

```
finish();
return;
```

Or use an if else

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.layoutb);
  if(good data){
      //do stuff
  }else{
      finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: First suggestion of "simply adding return" worked! After it gets to return, ClassA on resume is called, then Class B onDestroy is called.

Comment: Simply adding return; shows errors thereafter for unreachable code. To bypass this use the return in `if`

Answer (score 23):

It seems like `finish()` does not work until `onCreate()` return control to system. Please refer to this post: [about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android). You have to consider this issue if you don't want any of your code to be executed after calling finish.

Hope it helps.