# Start new Activity and finish current one in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, flags, start-activity

Currently I'm starting a new `Activity` and calling `finish` on a current one.

Is there any flag that can be passed to `Intent` that enables finishing current `Activity` without a need to call `finish` manually from code?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use `finish()` method or you can use:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

And then there is no need to call `finish()` anymore.

```
<activity android:name=".ClassName" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

Comment: are you sure this does what you say? from android docs: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory attribute.

Comment: android:noHistory="true" is NOT the same as finish()!

Comment: Just use the finish(), don't use noHistory

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!

Comment: I have noticed 'noHistory' prevents the app from storing the screen entirely, meaning when the user minimises the app and re-opens it flings the user back to the starting activity. Finish() is better because the open screen is still cached for minimisation

Answer (score 100):

Use `finish` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, NextActivity.class);
finish();  //Kill the activity from which you will go to next activity 
startActivity(i);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` you can use in case for the activity you want to finish. For exampe you are going from A-->B--C. You want to finish activity B when you go from B-->C so when you go from A-->B you can use this flag. When you go to some other activity this activity will be automatically finished.

To learn more on using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY does the opposite. New activity is not saved in history, whereas I want previous Activity being finished.

Comment: doesn't `finish()` suppose to kill the current activity ? how do you expect it to reach the next line `startActivity(i)` ? Looks dangerous and unexpected to me

Comment: @Michael Calls are async startActivity() will get called.

Comment: @tomi could you explain this "Calls are async startActivity() will get called." more precisely?

Comment: you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing

Answer (score 6):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY when starting the activity you wish to finish after the user goes to another one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG%5FACTIVITY%5FNO%5FHISTORY

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY does the opposite. New activity is not saved in history, whereas I want previous Activity being finished.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. Activity A you wish to finish, Activity B that is accessed from activity A. Start the activity A with the flag I mention so when the user roams away from activity a to activity B the activity A is finished. As I mentioned in the answer: "...when starting the activity you wish to finish...". It is the same answer as the confirmed one.