# Finishing old activity with noHistory

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to understand finishing an activity and starting another.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.blabla.game.OyunActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_oyun"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
```

OyunActivity :

```
int number = 1;
while(true)
{
if(number == 52)
{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
}
number++;
Log.d("TAG", number);
}
```

It's starting GameOver activity but OyunActivity not finishing. It's keeping increase number variable and outputting it to Logcat.

PS : Actually my code not really stupid like this. I'm trying to make a basic game. It should stop and open GameOver activity when number = 52

Comment: while(true) means that your loop will run indefinitely !

Comment: @Ty221 , i know . I want to finish() an activity's all process immediately and start another one.

Comment: If think that better solution is : `while(number != 52)`

Comment: I can't use it. Because actually my code hasn't any while loop :) used it here for simplify question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `break` instead of `finish()`

```
 int number = 1;
while(true)
{
if(number == 52)
{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
}
number++;
Log.d("TAG", number);
}
```

Comment: this time it will break only while loop, and continue from outside loop?

Comment: It will continue to finish al the code in the method and then GameOver will be launched. If you do not want to continue with other code use return instead of break.

Comment: Probably return; will solve my problem. I'll try and share results.

Comment: solved. @Hoan can you edit your answer please. I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308198/start-new-activity-and-finish-current-one-in-android) will be helpful for you, I think.

Quotation :

```
You can use finish() method or you can use:

android:noHistory="true"

And then there is no need to call finish() anymore.

<activity android:name=".ClassName" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

Comment: You read my question? Look at 5th line of my question please.