# Android StartActivity kill the exisiting activity first and its ondestroyed should get called and Switch to new Activity

Tags: android

Android StartActivity kill the Activity1 first and its ondestroyed should get called. Once this completes then open another activity.

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
                        finish();
```

even if i call finish first in this scenario Activity1 ondestroy method get call after Activity2 is shown to user. I am looking for proper way where i can be sure that Activity1 get destroyed completely then only show Activity2

Answer (score 0):

You can call finish(), and call startActivity() inside onDestroy():

```
void onDestroy() {
  startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabye `noHistory` atrribute helps you to get rid of this problem

```
<activity android:name=".ClassName" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

also, take a look at this post :
[Start new Activity and finish current one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308198/start-new-activity-and-finish-current-one-in-android)