# Press back button on main activity opens other activity

Tags: java, android

In my project i move from main activity to activity A and from activity A to activity B. From activity B using home menu on toolbar i jump back to main activity. Now when i press back button application should exit but it opens the activity A again.

Comment: how do you jump back to Main Activity?

Comment: by clicking on the home menu icon on the toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the launch flags to manage your activities in the back stack. As far as I understood your scenario, I think you need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for starting your main/home activity.

Read more about launch flags: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Also, take a look this for more details on managing activity back stack on Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManagingTasks

Comment: np. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the `finish()` method before starting the next activity to have it removed from the activity. Find more details and options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308198/start-new-activity-and-finish-current-one-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin write this in your **MainActivity** :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true)
    exitProcess(-1)
}
```

For Java write this in your **MainActivity** :

```
@Override
void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true)
    exitProcess(-1)
}
```

Hope to it will work for you as good as for me

Answer (score -1):

hey i write some code for you
Variables:

boolean backactivity = true;

CODE:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(backactivity==true)
        {
            finishActivity(1);
            backactivity=false;
        }else
        {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
```