# finish() and the Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm learning Android programming for a class, and I have a quick question about how finish() fits into the Activity lifecycle.

When you make a call to finish(), what lifecycle callback is started? I presume it's onPause(), then onStop() and onDestroy(). Is this correct?

Really, I just want to make sure that it doesn't jump straight to onDestroy().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.  onPause, onStop, onDestroy.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) are the docs.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I didn't actually see that series before (I've been looking at the API docs only). Raises some other questions, though - for instance, I thought that onDestroy() would be used as a "destructor," not onStop(); and that all persistent data should be written in onPause(). Learn something new every day, I guess...

Comment: **NO! NOT EXACTLY** see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle/30227647#30227647

Answer (score 8):

> Really, I just want to make sure that it doesn't jump straight to onDestroy(). ???

### NO!

but there is **one exception** when **calling finish() result in activity lifecycle break** this happens when u call finish() from onCreate() method in which case **onDestroy() will be immediately called!**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: First, the link is outdated. Here's a current version: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
Second, shouting "NO!" is a pretty rude way to answer a question, especially when you do it both in your own answer, *and* in a bunch of replies to other peoples' answers.
Having said that, yes, this is correct.

Comment: I agree that the giant "NO" is unpleasant, however I think the information in the post is very relevant and something people would want to see when finding this question.  I am personally up voting it.

Answer (score 3):

*Yes, it will not jump to onDestroy() skipping the onPause and onStop.*

Also you might be interested in **onPostResume() ,onPostPause() ,onPostCreate(),onUserLeaveHint()**, etc ....
These are not listed out in the activity life cycle

Comment: Those are excellent lesser-known methods but I don't believe there is an `onPostPause()`.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate. I'm learning there's a lot that's not mentioned in most Android books.

Comment: **NOT EXACTLY** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle/30227647#30227647

Answer (score 1):

It could also be very interesting for you to analyze such problems and issues. You can for example set a debuggin-breakpoint in the **onPause()** method and investigate the program flow from this point.

Also some print-outs can give you some helpful information.

You could for example write System.out.println("name of the method" + " called."); in each method of your activity which you think is called. (Overwrite for example **onPause()**, call **super.onPause()** and place a console print-out to see if the method is called.

You will learn a lot about the Android system doing such little investigations while you develop.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Android App and place this in the main activity.

Then view the LogCat window (under Android's DDMS) for the outputs

Build you application the same − add all the onPause, onStop, etc. methods with outputs to the LogCat.

As your program runs you can monitor what is called and at what times.

```
package com.app.myapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MyApp extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 

        Button exit = new Button(this);
        exit.setText("finish");
        exit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("MyApp", "finish");
                finish();
            }
        });

        layout.addView(exit);

        setContentView(layout);

        Log.v("MyApp", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onRestart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        Log.v("MyApp", "onStop");
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this suggestion (and Jan Koester's) is that I can't test for situations when the Android system automatically destroys an Activity in order to free resources. Or if there is a way, I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can use Java's ``finalize`` method.  Before the GC destroys an object it will make a call to this method.  Use a system-out or a call to LogCat.  In addition, check out the Settings and Dev Tools in the Android emulator, there are some handy features that may help you.  Here's the link: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html