# How to close an activity while going through the life cycle destruction?

Tags: android

What is the android way of closing/finishing an activity and still wanting it to go through `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroy`?

I am aware of `Activity.finish()`, however that will only guarantee calling `onDestroy()` not the other two. Reason, based on the android documentation, database access should be done in `onStop()` so it doesn't slow down the user, which is my intent, to keep all "saves" to the `onStop()`, however, I just noticed that that function is not called when `finish()` is called...

So.. what is the solution in this case? I mean, I can create a `boolean` variable, but is there is a more sophisticated way? Even another way to end an activity, like invoking `onDestory()` is that something incorrect to do?

**EDIT**

Sorry I misstyped that part, I meant to say save to database in `onStop()`, not in `onDestroy()`.

> Although the onPause() method is called before onStop(), you should
>   use onStop() to perform larger, more CPU intensive shut-down
>   operations, such as writing information to a database.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Activity.finish does go through the **activity life cycle**: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Also the documentation for [**onDestroy()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) states:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!

The [**onPause()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) states:

```
This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to do things like stop animations and other things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are exclusive access such as the camera.
```

And one last thing, for [**onStop()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29):

> Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's process running after its onPause() method is called.

Which leaves you just with **onPause()** as the method to override and perform some saving stuff. And it is indeed called.

In found a related question here: [finish() and the Activity lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Terribly sorry, I miss typed something, I edited the question, please have a look at it again, the Edit part is sufficient to see my mistake.

Comment: You are left with those two options. It really depends how slow is your database code, and whenever it is important to always save the data (since if the device is running low on memory your activity will miss the onStop call). If it just saving a few rows I would go to onPause() to avoid the user losing his work.

Comment: okay, but if I want to terminate the activity from a dialog alert, can I force it to go through the `onStop()`? because `finish()` doesn't go through `onStop()' only `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Re-read Activity documentation, use onPause(): " Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation."

Comment: Or just save the data in that dialog, which could be even easier (but more prone to future errors).

Comment: Now I am very confused, why would they put both of these: "Although the onPause() method is called before onStop(), you should use onStop() to perform larger, more CPU intensive shut-down operations, such as writing information to a database." and "Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation."

Comment: and "Be aware that these semantics will change slightly between applications targeting platforms starting with HONEYCOMB vs. those targeting prior platforms. Starting with Honeycomb, an application is not in the killable state until its onStop() has returned."

Comment: Yes documentation not very clear about this things. If you application is really very heavy and hangs while saving to database you can try doing partial writes during the life-span of you activity.

Comment: Be aware that there are still many 2.3.3 devices out there :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, "*if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be called. Therefore, you should use onPause() to write crucial persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. However, you should be selective about what information must be retained during onPause(), because any blocking procedures in this method block the transition to the next activity and slow the user experience*."

Which means, *OnPause()* is the correct method for DB operations, but if they are too heavy as to block the UI transition, only then they should be done in *OnStop()*