# When in the Fragment lifecycle is it best to store/restore persistent data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment which holds data that needs to be written to persistent storage. I'm having a difficulty deciding on which state in the Fragment lifecycle I should do this writing. Consider that there might be a significant amount of data to write so I wouldn't want to do it too frequently.

The options I have considered:

1. Write on **onPause**, Read on **onResume** : Wasteful, and will write the data on each fragment transaction or when the user switches to another application.
2. Write on **onDestroy**, read on **onActivityCreated**: Documentation says explicitly the onDestroy might not be called on some occasions if Android decides to kill the app instantly to free memory.
3. Write on both **onDestroy** and **onSaveInstanceState**, read on **onActivityCreated** and **onViewStateRestored** : That seems like the right way to do it for me but I can't seem to find support for that in the SDK documentation.

I'd appreciate your best practices.

Comment: Almost the same question as I had, hope some of that info helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495976/how-to-close-an-activity-while-going-through-the-life-cycle-destruction

Comment: The answer suggests saving on onPause and restoring on onResume (for Activities at least). While I implemented a write-on-dirty mechanism for my data, reading it from storage on each onResume is out of the question. I can use a flag for deciding whether it is the first time the fragment is instantiated and checking it in onActivtyCreated but I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: More like the answer suggested there is no clear one way that Android has recommended, it is more of a mess, and do what works best for each scenario. Which I think is a downfall for Android development. That was my conclusion. In any case, good luck :) PS: out of curiosity, how did you implement the `write-on-dirty`?

Comment: Nothing special - I just used a bitmask for marking certain parts of the data as dirty or not. When writeback takes place only the files which are related to dirty parts are written.