# Activity lifecycle after finish() has called

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-support-library

I wonder if `onSaveInstance()`, `onPause()` and `onStop()` are called if I call `finish()` or the lifecycle jumps directly to `onDestroy()`.

I also would like to know if android.support.v4 library's `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is always called or just when the activity is recreated because of a configuration change (can I trust it when the activity is stopped and put on the backstack?)

thanks

Comment: **It depends when you call finish()**

see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle/30227647#30227647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much test you frist question your self by adding a log on all those methods. As for you 2nd, onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() is called when its being recreated.

This method is used in ActivityThread class to destory the activity and has these lines of code:

```
3424try {
3425    r.lastNonConfigurationInstances
3426            = r.activity.retainNonConfigurationInstances();
3427} catch (Exception e) {
3428    if (!mInstrumentation.onException(r.activity, e)) {
```

activity.retainNonConfigurationInstances(); then will trigger onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

And also, if you look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29), here are some imporant lines:

> A new instance of the activity will always be immediately created
>   after this one's onDestroy() is called. In particular, no messages
>   will be dispatched during this time (when the returned object does not
>   have an activity to be associated with). The object you return here
>   will always be available from the getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
>   method of the following activity instance as described there. These
>   guarantees are designed so that an activity can use this API to
>   propagate extensive state from the old to new activity instance, from
>   loaded bitmaps, to network connections, to evenly actively running
>   threads.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to log the callbacks, but I wanted to make sure that I got it right :-)
This fulfills my needs.

Answer (score 6):

This will answer the first part of your question.

If you call `finish()` anywhere outside of onCreate(), then `onPause()` and `onStop()` will be called, but not if you call it from [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) :

> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case
>   onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest of the
>   activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.

`onSaveInstanceState()` won't be called even if you call `finish()` outside of `onCreate()` because the user will never be able to return to the activity so it will never need to restore its state.

Comment: got it! Thank you very much. Now I have a clear point of view about activity's lifecycle (the documentation often scatters these useful pieces of information and that does not help having it clear at once). Again, thanks