# Is it possible to block onStart() and onResume() to be called after onCreate()?

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I am finishing my activity in onCreate() and I don't want any other activity lifecycle method to be called after this. I can do this by defining a flag. But what I am looking for is if android provides some way to block these lifecycle methods. Is it possible?

Comment: You should probably go through this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html,

Comment: its activity life cycle they must called http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655898/finish-and-the-activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't alter the Activity Architecture/Lifecycle of Android.