# Why new Activity's onDestroy() is called?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-lifecycle

My code destroy my current activity and start a new activity, like below:

```
Intent intent = myActivity.getIntent();

myActivity.finish(); //Destroy my activity

myActivity.startActivity(intent); //Start my new activity
```

It works, the previous activity is destroyed and new activity starts, but **AFTER** start the new activity, the activity's `onDestroy()` method is called, why?

Comment: ignore `myActivity.finish();` this line.

Comment: Because the .finish() is calling the onDestroy() method.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing

Comment: Yes, onDestory() is called when I finish the previous activity, but when I start a new activity it also called, that's what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Start your new Activity first, and then finish the old.

Answer (score 0):

From the android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):-

> **protected void onDestroy ()**
>
> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can
> happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
> [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
> instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
> these two scenarios with the [isFinishing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) method.

Comment: Please check my question carefully. Of course onDestroy() will be called because I destroy the previous activity, my question is why the onDestroy() is called after start a new activity.

Comment: I guess he means onDestroy is called on the activity that has just been started... having same question my self