# What can be the reasons of an Android app that uses cpu where it shouldn't be?

Tags: android, android-activity, background-process, cpu-usage

I put finish() to backpressed method of my MainActivity but when i monitor cpu usage, I still see my app on the top of the list with cpu usage between %1 to %6.

I have no services running, I can't debug the currently open threads. So I don't know what's going on here.

Do you have any ideas? Whay can be the reason for an app keep using cpu even it was closed?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544310/what-happens-when-all-activities-of-an-application-finishes

Comment: @MorrisonChang I can accept it to stay in the process list, but it uses cpu and I can't find why it uses it, I couldn't use Debug to see the active threads to identify what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put finish() to backpressed method of my MainActivity

Please simply remove your `onBackPressed()` handler, or use `super.onBackPressed()`. Do not override `onBackPressed()` to call `finish()`.

> when i monitor cpu usage, I still see my app on the top of the list with cpu usage between %1 to %6

You fail to indicate how you are monitoring CPU usage. Assuming that you are correct in your analysis, then you have leaked a thread that is doing work.

> I can't debug the currently open threads

I have no idea what you mean by this statement. Use Traceview to monitor what code in your app is running.

Comment: Thank you, eventhough I couldn't directly use traceview (Monitor app),  I was able to find "Devices" window in Eclipse, which has some of the similar features of Monitor app. That way, I started profiling to record called methods and I was able to find called functions with this. Tough, if you have any other suggesstions I'll be looking forward to them.