# Android: Will finish() ALWAYS call onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, ondestroy, activity-finish

Simple question: can you be sure that `finish()` will call `onDestroy()`? I haven't found any confirmation on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing#answer-10862977

Comment: not always, as reported in the documentation

Comment: @blackbelt, could you refer to that specific documentation?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Simple question: can you be sure that finish() will call onDestroy()?

First, this answer assumes that you are referring to Android's `Activity` class and its `finish()` method and `onDestroy()` lifecycle method.

Second, it depends upon your definition of "sure":

- Your process could be terminated in between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`, for reasons independent of whatever is triggering the call to `finish()`
- A device manufacturer or ROM modder could introduce some screwy change that would break the connection between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`
- The battery could go dead in between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`
- Etc.

Third, `finish()` does not *call* `onDestroy()`. You can tell that by reading [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). `finish()` usually *triggers a call* to `onDestroy()`.

Generally speaking, `finish()` will eventually result in `onDestroy()` being called.

Comment: Within a process, can I rely on onDestroy()? Say, I have A, B, C, D, E activities, and want to finish all but E, then will all onDestroy() methods be called? The battery and memory state don't count here.

Comment: @Jenix: If the process is not terminated, and you do not trigger a crash (unhandled exception), finishing an activity will cause `onDestroy()` to be called on that activity.

Comment: Too fast haha. Thank you!

Comment: When exactly would calling finish() not trigger a call of onDestroy (assuming onDestroy wasn't called yet and the app is still alive) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: `finish()` is not `final`, so it could be overridden, and the overridding implementation might choose to not chain to the superclass in some cases for some strange reason. And, it is at least theoretically possible for a crash to occur between `finish()` and `onDestroy()`, though I don't know of any scenarios for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've seen today a weird case of this. I've overridden `onDestroy` and `finish` and only added logs to see that indeed they get called. It's really weird but for some reason I got `finish` to be called, but not `onDestroy`. That's why I ask. It's the first time I saw such a weird thing. No idea how to fix it either. And it's not like that the UI doesn't get a chance to do anything. I've seen `finish` being called multiple times later and still the Activity didn't call `onDestroy` even once.

Comment: @CommonsWare Never mind. I think I got it. I reached a very old code that for some reason had "synchronized" on the current Activity via a background thread, while also calling "setResult" (which synchronizes on the current Activity, too) on the UI thread. So it caused weird issues (probably ANR or deadlock, or something similar).

Answer (score 6):

**No you cannot be sure!**

Calling finish() generally triggers onDestroy() as per the Activity life cycle but you cannot rely on it. Specifically not for saving your data. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) clearly says

```
do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!
```