# activity is not stopping in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In android my activity is not stopping when I am returning to the main menu by back buttons.

So i used below code to stop the application from running. But when I hit back button it's showing Unfortunately,application has stopped. So is there a simple way where I stop my application from running when I return to main menu or by back button.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
        this.finish();
      }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lightsui"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/My_Theme" 
       >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lightsui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should not call `finish()` in `onDestroy()` since your activity is already finishing.  Are you override the back key?

Comment: @Simon  No I am not overriding the back key.                                         I have only one screen. So what I want is when I hit back key my app should not be running. But without using the above code it was running that's why i used the above code.

Comment: Finish could actually call onDestroy, so you are creating a loop. When you return to main menu, you app just pauzes (onPauze). This will not call onDestroy immediately (only when Android terminates the app).

Comment: @RobinDeCroon  `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called unless you call `finish()`.

Comment: @Simon Thanks, I based my comment on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892032/1741111 Thats why I was confused.

Comment: @Simon is there a specific time when our application is killed or stop in android or we have to do it manually by using some method.

Comment: You should not try to kill your app.  Let Android manage that.  Both of the answers below are good.

Comment: What do you mean by "app is still running"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you dont want the activity to be present when you go back, thats easy to achieve (it is stopping itself but just resuming when you return via the back key)

Add the following flag to the activity in your manifest to get the behaviour you require:

```
  android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: Are you using any other flags on your manifest entries/intents? Can you post them in your question

Comment: can you please elaborate like which flags etc.

Comment: Post your manifest and if you are switching activities with intents, post those blocks of code too

Comment: Done. I have added in the question.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept this answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks!