# how to start intent service on application destroy from MainActivity.class

Tags: android, android-service

> This method is in Mainactivity.class. I want this method to be called when application destroys

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (singleQuestion.size() > 0) {
            LastQuestionService.answerLastQuestion(context, singleQuestion.get(0));
        }

        super.onDestroy();

        MyLog.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

Comment: It automatically calls when activity destroy.

Comment: Use service instead of intent service in your case

Comment: it is not always called when activity destroys as i checked it using logs

Answer (score 0):

It automatically calls when an activity is destroyed. For example when you press back button, the activity will be destroyed and onDestroy() method will be called. But what if you press, Home or Menu butoon, then onDestory() method will not be called, rather onPause() method will be called.
So to check that, override OnUserLeaveHint(), it will be called in that case.

Comment: if the user press HOME button and then clear Applications running in background, the application will destroy.

Comment: i want to start service on application destroy and not on activity destroy as onDestroy() method is not always called from activity

Comment: When your user force kill the application like what you mentioned, i don't think your app will be notified as there will be no callbacks due to the entire process being killed.

Comment: It do call onDestroy() method when i kill application but the method is not always called (i checked this by putting Log in onDestroy method) .

Comment: okay, in that case, ill start a service when the app starts. Make a singleton approach for the application context. Run a timer task in that service & check if that appContext is null or not. If it is null means the app is destroyed, start the service you wanted & stop that timertask service.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try putting it within `finish()` instead. It will eventually call `onPause()` > `onStop()` follow by `onDestroy()`. Using `finish()` kills the activity and releases the memory, so you could effectively say that your application is killed since I supposed you will press the back button to close the app.

Note that `finish()` may not necessary call `onDestroy()` due to multiple reasons. Read this up for more info [Android: Will finish() ALWAYS call onDestroy()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891969/android-will-finish-always-call-ondestroy)

Comment: When  user force kill the application running in background,i want to call the service from my activity to save the data

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: It's not possible. As I mentioned, there will be no callbacks to your app when the user force kill the app.

Answer (score 0):

Imo, the problem is about both energy consuming issue and `context` values.
Possible solutions:

1. May be `singleQuestion.size() > 0` is false? :)
2. Use either `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` instead of `context`.
3. Call broadcast event into `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` [url](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) which launches your own service
4. Use `startForeground` notification inside your `Service` to prevent your process to be  killed. [url](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Comment: 1) list size is not 0 
2)my context is not null as i initiated it as Context context = MainActivity.class in that activity

Comment: When  user force kill the application running in background,i want to call the service from my activity to save the data

Comment: It might be null in while execution after `onDestroy()`. And, please, use `getContext()` instead of `Context context = MainActivity.class`

Comment: @DhanrajNaik , this is not possible to detect this action.

Comment: @DhanrajNaik , look here . it can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33078782/1979882

Comment: @DhanrajNaik , approve if it was helpful