# Android finish during onStop doesn't trigger onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I created a basic sample application that all it does is call `finish()` during the Activity `onStop()`. Based on my understanding and from looking at other posts on Stackoverflow, this should trigger `onDestroy()`.

My repro steps are launch the application, press the Home button on the device, which will trigger `onStop()`. The expected result is that it also hits `onDestroy()`, but I'm not seeing that.

If I call `finish()` during `onPause()` instead, it will trigger `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` as expected.

Anyone know why it would work during `onPause()` but not `onStop()`?

I've also noticed this message in the Logcat

> I/ActivityManager: Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{203ab0 u0 com.amazon.myapplication/.MainActivity t96 f}

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Sample", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d("Sample", "onStart");
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("Sample", "onResume");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("Sample", "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d("Sample", "onStop");
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("Sample", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Your code is working on my device. You can try placing finish() method after  super.onStop() method

Comment: @RakeshGupta I tried placing the finish() method after super.onStop() and still wasn't able to get it to work. I've even tested this on the Android Emulator and get similar behavior.

Comment: As you can see in Logcat finish method is trying to stop activity which is already stopped. So in some device it is working differently.

Comment: @RakeshGupta so what is preventing onDestroy() from being triggered?

Comment: I think onDestroy() will be called only after onstop() is successfully executed by finish() which is not happening here.

Comment: @RakeshGupta When I run `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` I do see that the activity is in the FINISHING state, but it takes about 5 minutes till I actually see onDestroy() getting called. Seems weird why it takes so long.

Comment: Don't know much about it. I think after 5 min minutes of inactivity, android system is destroying the app's activity to reclaim memory for other purposes.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19891969/6246513