# Android Activity Lifecycle Handling

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am new to android programming and would like to make clear the concept of Activity Lifecycle.

To make it simple, I have shortened the case as below:

- There are 2 activities (MainActivity and Main2Activity).
- In MainActivity, a button is created to open Main2Activity.
- In Main2Activity, in order to simulate user returning to MainActivity once Main2Activity is shown, it calls finish() and return to MainActivity in onCreate().

When the button is clicked, I found that there seems to have race condition occurred.

- MainActivity::onCreate() <-- 1st MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onStart() <-- 1st MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onResume() <-- 1st MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onPause() <-- 1st MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onCreate() <-- 2nd MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onStart() <-- 2nd MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onResume() <-- 2nd MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onStop() <-- 1st MainActivity instance
- MainActivity::onDestroy() <-- 1st MainActivity instance

The last onDestory() from the 1st MainActivity instance will run after the onCreate(), onStart(), onResume() from the 2nd MainActivity instance.

How can I ensure the onDestroy() is called before starting another activity?

Thanks very much for everyone's help.

---

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btnClick = findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // finish self
            finish();
            // start Main2Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // return to MainActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    // finish self
    finish();
}
```

Comment: nice question !

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? (AFAIK you can't do much about it, the runtime finishes/destroys Activities at its own pace. It depends on the Android version and the hardware as well as other factors like how many other apps are currently requesting resources)

Comment: What I plan is to release resources when the activity is destroyed. If the onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called before a new instance of the same activity is created, it will accidentally release singleton resources being using by another instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call `isFinishing()` on your first MainActivity instance.

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) for this method.

This would look like :

```
if (isFinishing()) {
  //onDestroy() has not been called yet
}
else {
  //onDestroy() has been called already
}
```

Comment: no, this is not what `isFinishing()` is checking. Read the docs you linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this approach to check the isFinishing() value in onPause() and to release resources if true.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `finish()` is explicitly called here. A call to this method will eventually trigger `onDestroy()`. See this answer for details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891969/android-will-finish-always-call-ondestroy

Comment: `isFinishing()` is in no way telling if `onDestroy()` was called as your comments suggest. In fact if it was, then your instance is already dead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure its the solution but give it a try..

on Main2Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

// return to MainActivity

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);    
       startActivity(intent);
     }
},5000);

// finish self
finish();
}
```

this would call the startActivity after 5 seconds .. that would give for the finish enough time to call all the life cycle

Comment: Using a time delayed approach seems not to be a good solution for race condition. Thanks anyway.