# Calling finish() after dismiss() has unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, activity-finish

I have an `Activity` that creates and shows a `Dialog` to show finishing progress. I want the `Activity` to `finish()` right after I `dismiss` the `Dialog`:

```
myDialog.dismiss();
finish();
```

But, when I do that, I see the screen rotate back (I force landscape, while the sensor says portrait). Also, the screen is black for some time.

When I postpone my `finish()` call with a `Handler`, I do not see that behaviour (it closes straight into the previous `Activity`):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       finish();
   }
}, 5000);
```

What is going on here?

**Update** I call `finish()` from a `Runnable` that is invkoed from a `Handler`. Perhaps that's part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call dismiss, just try out by calling finish [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862977/992063), since finish will close any dialog

Comment: Yes, it closes it, but it seems to rotate back to portrait. Also, the screen is black for a short time. When I use the `Handler` , it closes cleanly.