# Is GC guaranteed to free memory of unused activities

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, activity-lifecycle

I am trying to analyze the memory usage of the `Android` app. I do that using

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo <package name>
```

My app has only one `Activity` and I repeat the following steps probably a dozen of times:

1. open the app;
2. exit using the back button

After doing that a dozen of times `dumpsys` shows that around 1-2 instances of my `Activities` are still in memory. After I hit `adb dumpsys` for a couple of times the `Activity` count goes down to zero. Is this normal? If it is a leak I don't expect the `Activity` count to go down to zero. Does that mean `GC` claims the memory of the `Activity` objects slowly?

Comment: Try analyzing your app's memory usage with LeakCanary https://github.com/square/leakcanary. You will be able to pinpoint the problem much easier.

Comment: @EricBachhuber Thank you. I did use Leak canary and got rid of the leaks. All I am left with now is only false positives, Leak Canary thinks that activity has leaked and later says that "GC was being lazy". So I think Leak canary wise I have no leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that mean GC claims the memory of the activity objects slowly?

Finishing an `Activity` by pressing the back button does not mean its instance will be immediately killed and the memory `GC`-ed. The `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method is not a "finalizer". One can meet the case when by the time of starting a new `Activity` instance the "old" one is still sitting in memory (as a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing/10862977#10862977)).

> If it is a leak I don't expect the activity count to go down to zero.

If you see the app's process running it's not a leak as *"the activity count goes down to zero"*.

> After I hit adb dumpsys for a couple of times the activity count goes down to zero. Is this normal?

Yes, by the reasons described above.