# Why the lifecycle of an Asynctask or a Runnable is different from the Activity's lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runnable, android-lifecycle, ondestroy

For example, if we consider the snippet code below:

```
public class HandlerExample extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mLeakyHandler = new Handler();
    private TextView myTextBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_samples);
        myTextBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_handler);

        // Post a message and delay its execution for 10 seconds.
        mLeakyHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myTextBox.setText("Done");
            }
        }, 1000 * 10);
    }
}
```

When the `Activity` gets destroyed, whether by a configuration change or another reason, the `Runnable` will not. The same goes for `Asynctask`s.

My question is, what makes it not being destroyed even if it's declared in that `Activity`?

Consider that I am asking about the why.

Comment: if you dont mess with threads and activity lifecycle, loaders are best options for u. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: its different because they are not an Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Because **Activity** class runs on **UI Thread** and **Runnable**, **AsyncTask** etc run on **Background Threads** that are separate from the ui thread. And ending the Activity won't end other threads unless you specifically instruct it to do so.

[Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) Description:

> The **Runnable** interface should be implemented by any class whose
>   instances are **intended to be executed by a thread**.

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Description:

> **AsyncTask** enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. **This class
>   allows you to perform background operation**s and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

and also you can learn more about [Threads](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) by reading the documentation.

Comment: The handler doesn't run on backgrounds threads all the times. It runs on the thread from which it was created. For the snippet code above, it runs on the UI thread since it was created on the UI thread.

Comment: The handler runs on the thread it is created on, handler is just an helper object to send and receive from the message queue. Destroying the activity will also destroy the handler but it won't destroy the runnable which runs on a different thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: on the UI Thread then i call `Runnable.run()` where will this run? i think you should clarify that in your answer though, and also i think the implementation of runnables and other interfaces have evolved from just puttin them in threads

Comment: @Super-califragilistic _"on the UI Thread then i call Runnable.run() where will this run?"_ On the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

> What makes it not being destroyed even if it's declared in that Activity?

When `new Handler()` is called on a thread (the main thread in your case), the `Handler` is associated with the `Looper`'s message queue of the thread, sending to and processing `Runnable`s and messages from the queue.  Those `Runnable`s and messages have a reference to the target `Handler`. Even though `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method isn't a "destructor", i.e. when the method returns the `Activity`'s instance won't be immediately killed ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing/10862977#10862977)), the memory cannot be GC-ed because of an implicit reference to the `Activity` as being an outer class of the `Runnable`. The `Activity` won't be GC-ed for the delay time, i.e. until the `Runnable` be de-queued from the `Looper`'s message queue and processed.

References:

1. [This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: IncomingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler)
2. [How to Leak a Context: Handlers & Inner Classes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)