# Finish is not working - activity

Tags: android

I want to finish my activity, tried:

```
finish();
Activity.this.finish();
finishAffinity();
```

killing process...

It's how I am opening activity from service:

```
           Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Axctivity.class);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);
        stopSelf();
```

After finish, activity is succesfully hidden but still stay on runnining apps list when I can restore it.

Comment: @Qiteq sorry but not, it's normal appcompat activity
I used finish in onCreate and onRestart, nothing more.

Comment: "still stay on runnining apps list" -- Android does not really have a "running apps" list. Do you mean the *recent tasks* list, that you get from pressing the RECENTS button (or, on devices lacking that button, long-pressing HOME)?

Comment: @CommonsWare - yes! exactly this list, device button with tasks. 
I want to remove it completly from this place.

Comment: @CommonWare - you should put in in answer, to grant you correct answer. android:excludeFromRecents="true"  made the job. Thx for right direction

Comment: actualy i can... ;/

Answer (score 0):

It's how finish() works. It doesn't destroy the object nor the activity.
The android OS keeps the processes around to speed up getting back into the applications.
See [what exactly Activity.finish() method is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing)