# finish() finish the activity but it is still on background

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have a question concerning the finish() method of an activity in android studio:

I have this simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my activity_main I simply have a button. When I click on the button the activity finishes and I go back to the main screen of the device...However, when I click on the menu button of the device (which shows all the app running in background) I still see my activity... and I do not want that. How can I fix it?

Comment: "However, when I click on the menu button of the device (which shows all the app running in background)" -- no, it does not. It shows recent tasks. None of those are necessarily "running", insofar as none necessarily have a running process. "and I do not want that" -- why? Or, more accurately, why do your *users* not want that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what exactly Activity.finish() method is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing)

Comment: To CommonsWare: Actually I had this question for another application more developed than this one. This application is an alarm and I had a button finish. When the screen is locked, the activity of the alarm appears at the time of the alarm. when I clik on the button: "finish the alarm" the alarm finished but it was it was in the recent tasks (thank you btw for this explanation!). And when I clicked on it it was ringing again...I hope I am clear

Comment: To Shiva: I saw this question but it didn't have my answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try using

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in your `Activity`  in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
            ...
             android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the activity has a thread running in the background to download data from the network, it may create that thread in `onCreate()` and then stop the thread here in `onDestroy()`
if you don't have new thread you can after `finish();` write `return;`