# Remove application (in foreground and background)

Tags: android, background

I have a question, I want to remove my application in foreground as well as in background.
My current code is:

```
.finishAffinity();
```

I've also tried:

```
.finishAffinity();
            System.exit(0);
```

However, the application is still in background mode.

Comment: What **precisely** do you mean by "still in background mode"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254861/finish-finish-the-activity-but-it-is-still-on-background

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically
Already discussed in this post/thread