# How to finish activity from ViewModel using Android's architecture components?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am trying to figure out the best way to finish an Activity from  a ViewModel. I found one way to do this using a LiveData object and emitting a "signal".

I have a doubt that this solution has a overhead. Is it the right solution or I should use more accurate?

Here's an activity which demonstrates this solution:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        model.shouldCloseLiveData.observe(this, Observer { finish() })
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val shouldCloseLiveData = MutableLiveData<Void>()

    fun someAction(){
        shouldCloseLiveData.postValue(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: And i think this is the correct solution, as you should never have references to your activity inside the ViewModel.

Comment: @woodii : I understand that solution is consistent with MVVM but posting null to send close request to activity. I'm wondering if exist more elegant solution.

Comment: I have created a similar solution to this one, but I'm also not happy with it, have you found any other solution for this problem?

Comment: @PozzoApps Nope. For some activities, in which I needed more actions, ViewModel sends a enum object.

Comment: I'm not a big expert with LiveData because I use RxJava but it should be the same. The only thing that I would change is sending a null. In RxJava2 they have even forbidden it: you can't emit nulls anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I share your feelings that this solution does not look tidy for two reasons. *First* using a `MutableLiveData` object to signal an event is a workaround. No data is changed. *Second* exposing LiveData to the outside of the view model violates the principle of *encapsulation* in general.

I am still surprised about this ugly concept of android. They should provide an option to observe the view model instead of it's internal `LiveData` objects.

I experimented with `WeakReference`s to implement the observer pattern. This was unstable. In an unpredictable manner the referent of the `WeakReference` was lost (`null`), in wich cases it was not possible to call `finish()`. This was surprising as I don't think the activity is garbage collected while running.

So this is an partly answer by exclusion. The observer pattern implemented as `WeakReference` seems to be no alternative to your suggestion.

A wonder if it is legitimate implement the observer pattern by hard references, if I remove the references during `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()`. I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000975/am-i-allowed-to-observe-a-viewmodel-if-i-clean-up-the-back-references).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Single Event, as you can see the implementation here:
https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af#file-event-kt

So, you don't have change the implementation of your activity

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        model.shouldCloseLiveData.observe(this, Observer { finish() })

    }
 }
```

The View Model will be like

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

  private val _shouldCloseLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
  val shouldCloseLiveData: LiveData<Event<Boolean>> = _shouldCloseLiveData
  
  fun someAction(){
      _shouldCloseLiveData.postValue(Event(true))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I had two activities (A and B) with its view models connected to an object (a table in a database): from an observable of a live data I had to navigate to another activity B (from A to B). The problem was, after invoking the new activity B, the observable in B change the value in the observed object.. activity A was still live, 
 its live data call again the navigation code to B.. in an infinite loop.

After some research, I realized running a `finish` method does not mean the activity is really [destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing).

The solution is, in the observable code, remove from the live data the observables linked to specific activity.

```
liveData.removeObservers(activity);
```

I show it in the following snippet code. It's written in Java, but I think you have no problem to read it. With this, I solved my problem.

```
public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...    

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ConfigurationViewModel.class);

        LiveData<Configurazione> liveData = mViewModel.getConfiguration();
        liveData.observe(this, config-> {
            // this code will be executed even another activity is in front of
            // screen
            boolean validToken = (config.getToken()!=null);

            if (!tokenValido) {
                intent = LoginActivity.createIntent(this);
            } else {
                intent = MainActivity.createIntent(this);
            }

            // this line remove the observable, so even activity will be destroied with calm, it is not a problem, the code is no more executed
            liveData.removeObservers(this);
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

I think you can easily adapt to this situation to your code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

A better way of doing this is using Kotlin Channels. I'll use LiveData for this example but you can also consume the Flow directly.

ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _event = Channel<MyEvent>()
    
    val event = _event.receiveAsFlow().asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)

    fun someAction() {
        _event.send(MyEvent.FINISH)
    }
}

enum class MyEvent {
    FINISH
}
```

And on the activity side:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        model.event.observe(this) {
            if (it == MyEvent.FINISH) {
                finish()
            }
        }

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            model.someAction()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Previous answer (not a good one):

I agree that there doesn't seem to be a good solution for this, and your suggestion does work pretty well. But I would suggest the following.

Since you are using Kotlin you could pass a function from your activity to the viewmodel like this:

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    
    fun someAction(block: () -> Unit) {
        // do stuff
        block()
    }
}
```

Activity: here the button (and clicklistener) is used as an example but this can be anywhere in the activity's code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        myButton.setOnClickListener {
            model.someAction() {
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `block` function will essentially act as a callback.

Comment: upvoting because of Kotlin

Comment: You are passing an implicit reference of activity to the ViewModel and it can cause memory leaks. it's clearly highlighted in the documentation: `Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.`  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: @HabibKazemi app is just passed to the AndroidViewModel, so not keeping the reference. Still this is not relevant to the question/answer, since this can be used with a ViewModel instead of an AndroidViewModel.

Here is an example (in Java) from android where the application is received in the constructor and passed to super().: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductViewModel.java

Comment: As per my understanding, this violates the rule. Here, though the finish() action will executed by the viewModel but the Activity took the decision of that action. Which is not a good practice for MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

one-lined method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <import type="android.app.Activity" />

        <import type="androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil" />

        <import type="androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->((Activity)(((ViewDataBinding)DataBindingUtil.findBinding(v)).lifecycleOwner)).finish()}"
            android:text="Exit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

or simplify the layout expression, move code to a helper class

```
public class DataBindingHelper {
    public static Activity findActivity(View v) {
        final ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(v);
        return binding != null ? (Activity) binding.getLifecycleOwner() : null;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <import type="com.xxx.settingitemmoretest.DataBindingHelper" />

        <import type="android.app.Activity" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.xxx.settingitemmoretest.MainActivity.ViewModel" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="@{viewModel.shouldCloseLiveData}"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(v, p)-> p ? DataBindingHelper.findActivity(v).finish(): void}"
            android:text="Stub Useless Button"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:checked="@{viewModel.shouldCloseLiveData}"
            android:onCheckedChanged="@{(v, p)-> p ? ((Activity)context).finish(): void}"
            android:text="Stub Useless Button"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

or use a Binding Adapter

```
public class ViewGroupBindingAdapter {

    @BindingAdapter({"android:shouldClose"})
    public static void setShouldClose(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean shouldClose) {
        if(shouldClose){
            final ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(viewGroup);
            if (binding != null) {
                ((Activity) binding.getLifecycleOwner()).finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.xxx.settingitemmoretest.MainActivity.ViewModel" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shouldClose="@{viewModel.shouldCloseLiveData}"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
     </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```