# What can keep activity alive after finish()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have `HomeScreen` and `LoginScr` activity and I would like to move from `HomeScreen` to `LoginScr` activity. I do it in such way:

```
val thread = Thread(Runnable {
    try {
     val client = APICallRequests.client
     client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
     client.connectionPool.evictAll()
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
     e.printStackTrace()
    }
})

thread.start()


val intent = Intent(this, LoginScr::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finishAfterTransition()
```

As you can see I try to close `okHttp3` client, because maybe it keeps `HomeScr` activity alive. Also I use `finishAfterTransition()`. Then when I move from LoginScr to HomeScr I do it in such way:

```
private fun moveToNextScreen(){
        val goToMain = Intent(this, HomeScreen::class.java)
        startActivity(goToMain
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
        )
        finishAfterTransition()
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    }
```

As I see I create two activity instances instead one. How I did it - added log to `onCreate()` fun. I totally don't understand why does it happen. Similar problem can be met after `onBackPressed()`:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
   startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
   startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
   startActivity(startMain)
   finish()
   super.onBackPressed()
}
```

I tried a lot of variants but my `HomeScreen` can stay alone. I also tried such ways at manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:noHistory="true"
```

Maybe someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862977/13221053
Further, if you want to keep your app active in background then you can use services for that purpose, here is the documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services