# Xamarin NullReferenceException when calling 'Finish()' on activity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a biometric authentication service that starts an activity and registers a callback to a static `EventHandler` for the result.

The handler:

```
public class BiometricHandler : IBiometricHandler
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<byte[]> taskCompletionSource;

    public Task<byte[]> StartBiometricAuth()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(BiometricActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

        taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
        BiometricActivity.BiometricEventHandler += BiometricCompleted;

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private void BiometricCompleted(object sender, BiometricEventArgs e)
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(e.Success ? e.Payload : new byte[] { });

        BiometricActivity.BiometricEventHandler -= BiometricCompleted;
    }
}
```

And the activity (not the actual code obviously):

```
public class BiometricActivity : Activity
{
    public static event EventHandler<BiometricEventArgs> BiometricEventHandler;
    private readonly int BIOMETRIC_REQUEST = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(BiometricAuth));
        StartActivityForResult(intent, BIOMETRIC_REQUEST);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        BiometricEventHandler?.Invoke(
            this,
            new BiometricEventArgs(
                true, new byte[] {1, 2, 3}
            );

        Finish();
        
    }
}
```

The above code throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal
0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125,4
0x20 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.57
0x6 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformConfigurationExtensions.OnThisPlatform<Xamarin.Forms.Application> at D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformConfigurationExtensions.cs:8,4
0xC in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FragmentContainer.OnResume at D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FragmentContainer.cs:126,4
0x8 in AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnResume at C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid12.0\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:2570,4
0x11 in Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.57
```

And the console:

```
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I narrowed it down to the `Finish()` method.
There is no exception when it is not called.

I tried calling `Finish()` from the handler using `BroadcastReceiver`, same result.

Why does `Finish()` throw this exception?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by calling `Finish()`? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862977/4984832

Comment: If you wrap Finish in try-catch, does the exception still happen? If so, there is something, somewhere, that you'll need to stop/unhook/clear/null/something-else before calling Finish. Or maybe need a WeakReference somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like the issue is an asynchronous race condition.
`Finish()` takes a bit longer to complete than the service to return the data.

Then the content page tries to perform a UI event, and since `Finish()` hasn't finished yet, the activity is still "visible" and the content page is not yet responsible for the UI thread. So the UI event fails with the exception.

Since there doesn't seem to be an easy way to `await` the `Finish()` call, I used `Task.Await` to delay the UI event for a bit and to `Finish()` complete.

Not ideal, but at least `NullReferenceException` is gone