# startActivity() doesn't start activity

Tags: java, android

I have a class called ShowBoardList where I check if user has logged in. If user hasn't logged in, then I want to return to the **MainActivity** which provides the user with buttons to login into different services.

My **AndroidManifests.xml** looks like this:

```
<application
   <activity android:name="im.chaitanya.TaskTimer.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="im.chaitanya.TaskTimer.WebViewActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="im.chaitanya.TaskTimer.ShowBoardList"
        android:label="Your Tasks">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**ShowBoardList.java** looks like this:

```
...
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(ShowBoardList.this, im.chaitanya.TaskTimer.MainActivity.class);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = intent.getStringExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); //url can be null here
Keys keys = new Keys(); //this gets an API key

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", 0);
String savedToken = settings.getString("token", "Empty");

if (MyUtils.equalsWithNulls(url,"tasktimer://oauthresponse#token=")) {
    Log.d("From ME:", "I've reached inside url check");
    mainActivityIntent.putExtra(caller, "ShowBoardList");
    //caller is a String. I'm storing the name of the current activity (ShowBoardList) in it. 
    //So that the main activity (which I'm trying to call) will know where the call came from.
    startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
}

if(savedToken.equals("Empty") || savedToken.equals("")) {
    String searchString = "#token=";
    int tokenIndex = url.indexOf(searchString) + searchString.length(); //Since url can be null there can be an error here
    String token = url.substring(tokenIndex);
    savedToken = token;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("token", token);
    editor.apply();
}
...
```

Condtion ***equalsWithNulls*** checks if url is ***null*** OR equal to the string in the argument. I have log statements there to check whether control reaches inside the if statement. The main activity however doesn't start.

**Edit:** onCreate() of **MainActivity.java** looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("mySettings", 0);
    String token = settings.getString("token", "Empty");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowBoardList.class);

    if(token != "Empty") {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    intent = getIntent();
    String callerActivity = intent.getStringExtra(ShowBoardList.caller);
    View coordinatorLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.snackbarPosition);

    if (callerActivity!=null && callerActivity == "ShowBoardList") {
        Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Permission Denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Is there any error? What happened? LogCat please.

Comment: I used the debugger to check what is happening. The control goes over that statement and on to the next line outside the if statement. There's no error over there. There *is* an error later on but that is because the the main activity isn't started and the program tries to call functions on a null object.

Comment: I added some more code. That should make it more clear as to what I'm trying to accomplish. But like I said there are no errors caused at the startActivity() statement.

Comment: `startActivity()` is not synchronous. It returns immediately and the activity gets started later. Is this your problem?

Comment: It might be. How do I wait for the activity to start?

Comment: Does your logcat prints this line "From ME:", "I've reached inside url check " ?

Comment: @KishuDroid - yes it does

Comment: Okey so what it caller ?

Comment: @KishuDroid - caller is a String. I'm storing the name of the current activity (ShowBoardList) in it. So that the main activity (which I'm trying to call) will know where the call came from.

Comment: can you paste the mainActivity here... may be it is started and come back to ShowBoardList again... due to conditions check on mainActivity.

Comment: @sourabhbans - I added that. ShowBoardList is indeed started from the mainactivity. However that only happens when the token variable has already been saved in ShowBoardList. This saving happens after the startActivity call is made in ShowBoardList.

I'll try adding a couple of Log statements to see if it comes back and then again goes to ShowBoardList.

Comment: @sourabhbans - You're right. ShowBoardList is being called again from MainActivity. Thanks for that! I need to see why this is happening now.

Comment: @sourabhbans - No. Scratch that. I miss read the log. That is not the problem.

Comment: try to use `(token!=null && !(token.equals( "Empty")))`... in stead of `(token != "Empty")` .. it(!=) will never check for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on Sourabh's comment on the question. I realised from my logs that the activity was indeed being started.

What I didn't realise was that when `startActivity()` is called, the calling activity (in this case `ShowBoardList`) is paused and when `ShowBoardList` was being called again, it would resume from after `startActivity()`.

Therefore the solution here was to call `finish()` and then `return` immediately after the startActivity() which ensures that onCreate is called the next time. I hope that makes sense if anyone is in the same situation.

These questions helped me understand more about `finish()`:

[about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android)

[onCreate flow continues after finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282569/oncreate-flow-continues-after-finish)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your new Intent wherever you required.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(ShowBoardList.this, im.chaitanya.TaskTimer.MainActivity.class);
newIntent .putExtra(caller, "ShowBoardList");

startActivity(newIntent );
```