# Why Activity is not finishing or destroying after calling finish() in onBackPressed()?

Tags: android

Friends In my activity i have placed `finish()` inside `onBackpressed()`, Still sometimes it is not finishing or destroying the activity.. What will be the issue?

Comment: are using Tabs in your Project?

Answer (score 5):

`super.onBackpressed()` will do the `finishing` thing for you, so dont comment this line after overriding this function.. add your extra functionality in this function if you have any...

Answer (score 1):

finish() just tells the activity to do what it needs to do to finish, eg. shutdown, call on onPause, report result to parent, etc. It doesn't do an exit() call or anything.

You should return after the finish() call.

also, see this question: [about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use finish(); inside onBackPressed();

please try this...

Answer (score -1):

sometimes finish() method not supported.
your OnBackPressed() method should have @Override notation.
bt this notation only supported in API level greater than 5.

for me it works.