# What does this.finish() really do? Does it stop my code running?

Tags: android

I'm a bit hazy about what exactly this.finish() does. Specifically, I just wrote the following lines of code in an activity:

```
this.finish();
Globals gs = (Globals) getApplication();
gs.MainActivity.finish();
```

The code is meant to close the current activity and also close the core activity of the app. And it works great. However, I got wondering... obviously the current activity isn't quite ended after the first line is executed. And what if I was to call this.finish() and then start on some complicated computation?

My question is: When I call this.finish(), when exactly does my Activity get taken down?

Comment: You could try logging the time between your calling finish() and your Activity's onDestroy() being called for a rough estimate on how long it takes.

Comment: There is a good reply here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22526967/2751547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, I am no expert, but at the answer here [about finish() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android) is basically what codeMagic just said.  The link is valuable because of the discussion regarding onStop() and onDestroy()

Comment: Whoop, you're right - I hadn't realised the question was a dupe (I was evidently using the wrong search terms!).

Answer (score 7):

Whatever method called `finish()` will run all the way through before the `finish()` method actually starts. So, to answer your question, after the calling method finishes then your activity will run its `finish` method. 
If you don't want the method to continue then you can add a return statement after `finish`

Answer (score 5):

> *I'm a bit hazy about what exactly this.finish() does*

Calling `finish()` basically just notifies the Android OS that your activity is ready to be destroyed.  Android will then (whenever its ready) call `onPause()` on the activity and proceed to destroy it (no guarentee onDestroy() will be called), via the activity lifecycle.  In general, you probably should not be doing any more execution after you call `finish()`.  According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), you should call `finish()` when you are ready to close the activity.

> *when exactly does my Activity get taken down?*

I am guessing your activity will simply be added to some destroy queue. During this time you might be able to continue executing until the OS destroys it. I believe you are for sure allowed to finish executing the method from which `finish()` was called.

Answer (score 2):

Activity.finish() will not stop the current activity until the method is completely executed so to skip the remaining part of the code, you may use a  return;  use it  with some  condition to validate your skip.

if ( condition = true ) {

```
      this.finish();
      return;
}
```