# Calling finish() in onStop()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

What happens when **`finish()`** method is called in **`onStop()`** method?

Does it causes **anr** : means it calls

> ***onPause()->onStop()->finish()->onPause()....***

or it **finishes the activity** : means it calls directly

> ***onDestroy()***

Actually, I want to ***finish*** my activity when it is completely ***invisible***.

***EDIT:***

> See this scenario, I launch an activity B whose layout height and
>   width is smaller than activity A, so activity A is partially visible
>   and when I press the home button activity A becomes completely
>   invisible. At this point I want to close activity A, so that it do not
>   call onRestart().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why not you are adding the code at onPause?

Comment: System will call onDestroy() method and Activity finishes as usual...

Comment: @PankajKumar what if Activity has a Dialog upon it? and what if finishing Activity in such cases ?

Comment: @PankajKumar As I already mentioned, I want to finish my activity when it is completely invisible, since onPause can be invoked when activity is partially visible.

Comment: @GopalRao can you point out some references too??

Comment: @GopalRao I don't think that onPause get called when you show Dialog from that activity. Check that.

Comment: @PankajKumar thanks for sharing your knowledge and updating me. but this may happen when Activities having theme Dialog.Theme (background Activity is partially visible and goes to onPause() state)

Comment: @GopalRao I am only talking about Dialogs, not the Activity which called as dialog. And yes there is no any perfect way to solve his question, until he let the Android to do his task. Thats what I was telling him.

Comment: @PankajKumar see my editted ques. I've added a scenario of what I'm talking about.

Comment: @GopalRao see my editted ques. I've added a scenario of what I'm talking about.

Comment: So you want to finish Activity A when the application goes to the background, leaving Activity B on the top of the stack? This sounds very strange.

Answer (score 3):

It finishes the activity and `onDestroy()` is called. If you want to finish your activity when it is invisible then you should call `finish()` in `onStop()`.

Comment: Need Some references @PratikGandhi

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android

Comment: there is no word regarding: calling finish() in onStop().

Comment: Any activity goes invisible when onStop() method is called and you want to finish your activity whenever it goes invisible, so calling finish() in onStop() will do the job.

Comment: see my editted ques. I've added a scenario of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I didn't get that 'one activity is smaller than another activity' but I want to help you out so put the screenshots where 2nd activity partially hides the 1st activity.

Answer (score 0):

according to your scenario, maintain one flag in MainActivity indicating that other Activity is launched or not? and make sure yourself to finish MainActivity or not based on that flag ...

this may help you...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean isSecondActivityLaunched;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isSecondActivityLaunched = false;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        isSecondActivityLaunched = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(!isSecondActivityLaunched) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be best way in your case to call finish() ;

Thanks

Comment: may be this will work.
but I dont want to close my whole application.

Comment: In Android finish() method only close the current activity from which finish() method called. If you would like to close whole application then there is another way. Same for System.exit() . It will close the current Activity. If my answer will help you then please support this. Thanks. :)

Comment: No no no! You should never ever call `System.exit()`. There is no reason for that. This is bad advice. Calling `System.exit()` will shutdown your entire process (including all your activities, services, etc.), not just this activity. And Android will think that your process crashed.

Comment: @DavidWasser what would you suggest in the scenario mentioned above in ques ??

Comment: @Susomrof I can't suggest anything yet, because I don't understand what OP is trying to do. That's why I asked my question in the comments. I'm trying to understand his problem before I suggest anything.