# How to determine if a finish() call has been made in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that a call to `finish()` does not cause the activity to return and exit its current scope immediately. It will continue to execute lines of code until it reaches a `return` statement or end of the method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish()

    // this still executes
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick - post finish()");
}
```

And I am aware that multiple methods called within a certain scope all continue to execute until completion when a `finish()` call is invoked. So in the code below each of the `Log.d` statements is shown in my Logcat.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    /* Perform a method */
    doThis();

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick - post finish()");
}

private void doThis(){
    Log.d(TAG, "doThis called");

    /* Perform another method */
    doThat();

    Log.d(TAG, "doThis - post finish()");
}

private void doThat(){
    Log.d(TAG, "doThat called");

    /* Finish the activity! */
    finish();

    Log.d(TAG, "doThat - post finish()");
}
```

Here is the Logcat output for the code above:

```
07-31 14:44:28.354  25367-25367/com.test.app D/MainActivity﹕ doThis called
07-31 14:44:28.354  25367-25367/com.test.app D/MainActivity﹕ doThat called
07-31 14:44:28.355  25367-25367/com.test.app D/MainActivity﹕ doThat - post finish()
07-31 14:44:28.355  25367-25367/com.test.app D/MainActivity﹕ doThis - post finish()
07-31 14:44:28.355  25367-25367/com.test.app D/MainActivity﹕ onClick - post finish()
```

EDIT: 
Is there a better way to stop all code execution when the `finish()` method is called? Perhaps using something like CoreyOgburn suggested with `willFinish() or`markedToFinish()`? Or maybe a way to`finishImmediately()`?

My code that is run after `finish()` has no way to know if the Activity is going to be finished. If I didn't want future code to run I would have to add a `return` statement after the `doThis()` and `doThat()`.

Comment: This is the best answer. finsih() will not begin until all the calls in queue are executed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590947/about-finish-in-android

Comment: If I may, I might want to tack on a small question that has a lot to do with this... is there a way to determine if the app is about to finish? like `willFinish()` or `markedToFinish()` that returns a boolean?

Comment: ^ that is essentially what I was getting at but @CoreyOgburn phrased what I was really after much better. I will edit this post.

Comment: read the doc. there is an `isFinishing` method

Answer (score 1):

I have a static  util function i use to make sure  i dont run into edge case of trying to continue with my general activity work when  finish is called.

```
    public static boolean activityNotFinished(Activity activity) {
    if (activity == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (activity.isFinishing()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (activity.isDestroyed()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finish is **NOT** terminating anything instantly. Unless you return from your `onCreate()` (or whatever) your activity lives. It is marked for killing but unless you return control to the framework it will NOT be killed.