# Finish Activity not close in Android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I have Two Activity one is `InventoryActivity` and Second is `StoneDetailActivity`. In my InventoryActivity have `RecycleView` In RecycleView Button Click I start the `StoneDetailActivity` using `StartActivityForResult` below code.

```
Intent stonedetailIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(StoneDetailActivity));
stonedetailIntent.PutExtra("SearchitemObject", stoneJson);
stonedetailIntent.PutExtra("position", position);
context.StartActivityForResult(stonedetailIntent, 1000);
context.OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.Slide_in_right, Resource.Animation.Fade_back);
```

In `StoneDetailActivity` Button click I use this code to Finish the current Activity and go to `OnBackPressed()`.

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
 {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.PutExtra("BoolCheck", postflag);
    intent.PutExtra("Position", position);
    SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
    Finish();
 }
```

and In `InventoryActivity` I have set this code.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {

                bool checkflag = data.GetBooleanExtra("BoolCheck", false);
                int position = data.GetIntExtra("Position", -1);
                if (checkflag && position > -1)
                {
                    searchItems.RemoveAt(position);
                    inventAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                    txt_totalStone.Text = searchItems.Count.ToString();
                    txt_totalCarat.Text = searchItems.Sum(c => c.Weight.Value).ToString();
                    txt_totalAmount.Text = searchItems.Sum(c => c.Rate.Value).ToString();

                    mainActivityBool = true;

                    badgeCounttextView.Text = BizApplication.BADGE_COUNT.ToString();

                }

            }
        }
```

**Button Click code :**

```
add_to_cart_button.Click += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pdialog.SetMessage("Please Wait...");
                    pdialog.Show();

                    cartItem = new CartItem();
                    cartItem.StoneId = searchItem.PacketId;
                    cartItem.UserId = BizApplication.getCredential().Id;
                    cartItem.Amount = searchItem.Rate.Value;
                    cartItem.Discount = searchItem.Discount;

                    postflag = await InventoryService.AddToCart(cartItem);

                    if (postflag)
                    {
                        OnBackPressed();
                        BizApplication.BADGE_COUNT += 1;
                    }

                    pdialog.Dismiss();

                };
```

this code work fine for first Time. But Again if I do the same process, the `StoneDetailActivity` set open eventhough if I click finish.

**UpDate :**

When I full debug my code and i found that when I click on Second time OnBackPressed(). and Finish it my debug again start the `OnCreate` activity that's why it happening. But I am not starting Again then Why is Happening.

What happen I don't understand. Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: When u debug are able to see the finish is calling() right?

Comment: @Raghavendra yes it finish but the Activity can't change and it display as a open ..

Comment: @Raghavendra see my update question ..

Comment: Just a test case, can you just call Finish() in onBackpressed and tell me what's happening.?

Comment: @Raghavendra nothing happen the Activity is not close because I start that activity using `StartActivityForResult` if the result is not getting in Previous Activity then `OnBackpressed` and `Finish` have no meaning ?

Comment: Just to test whether second time it'll finish the activity or not.

Comment: @Raghavendra In Second time After `Finish` it goes to `OnCreate` Method..that's why It display but I don't know why it goes to `OnCreate` method??

Comment: I don't know it in xamarin, but can u call return; after finish and try?

Comment: @Raghavendra i try that also but it not work. First I write return but it is not work and also void does not return that's why I remove it .

Comment: @Raghavendra By the way thanks for your support.

Comment: If its not a huge code can u post little more extra code where u r calling onBackpressed()

Comment: @Raghavendra i update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this Post the Problem was that inside `ListView` or `RecycleView` if we are perform some task like `OnclickListener` then we have check is `OnclickListener` like below way other it will fire multiple event.

```
 if (!button.HasOnClickListeners)
    {
        button.Click += this.clickHandler;
    }
```

Then the code is working fine.

For more detail visit this :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9244/single-click-on-button-invoking-multiple-clicks

Answer (score -2):

try by adding flag **Intent**

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: have you see the docs. if not then see this : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnBackPressed()/

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);