# Passing finish activity before all lines are executed - android

Tags: java, android

If we call the acitivty.finish() and there are some lines of code below that. will that be executed once the finish() has been called? or ignored?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590947/8089770

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If we call the acitivty.finish() and there are some lines of code below that. will that be executed once the finish() has been called?

**`Yes`** Because `acitivty.finish()`  is not an abort

CHECK this Example

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("TEST", "BEFORE FINISH");
        finish();
        Log.e("TEST", "AFTER FINISH");
        Log.e("TEST", "AFTER FINISH");

    }
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: But if i use intent before finish and add this lines after finish.. will it work?

Comment: @VishvaDave After calling finish() your activity will not be immediately finished but only planned to be 'finished'. So execution of code will continue